# IndentationError: expected an indented block (python codeacademy)

Tags: python, indentation

I was taking my course at codeacademy until something went wrong and couldn't proceed, a little help please :( here is my code

```
def by_three(num):         
    if num%3 == 0:
        def cube(num):        
    else:        
        print "False"

def cube(num):  
    return num**3

by_three(9)
```

I get...

```
File "<stdin>", line 4  
else:  
^  
IndentationError: expected an indented block  
Unknown error.
```

I will really appreciate your help people!!

Comment: You should backspace the else then just press tab once. I feel like this isn't Stack Overflow worthy though...

Comment: You need to get more up to speed to ask a legitimate question.
You have `def cube(num):` which would be what's used to define a function. Not sure why that's there but that's the cause of your syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted to *call* (use) the function `cube()` instead of *defining it*
 (in your `by_three()` function definition), so your corrected code will be:

```
def by_three(num):         
    if num%3 == 0:
        print cube(num)          # Instead of your original "def cube(num):"       
    else:        
        print "False"

def cube(num):  
    return num**3

by_three(9)
```

Answer (score 0):

On line 3 `def cube(num):` you have an extra `def` and `:`. Remove those

When defining a function you need `def` and colon, where as for calling it you don't need one. The correct code

```
def by_three(num):    
    if num%3 == 0:
        cube(num)
    else:    
        print "False"

def cube(num):  
    return num**3

by_three(9)
```